# Using Python calculate the 1000 prime number

Tags: python

I am attempting to find the 1000 prime number and am trying to do it without cheating memorization or other code. Can you please tell me whether I am on the right track with my code or completely off base?

```
primes = []
num = 3
while (len(primes)) < 1000:
    if num / 2 == 0:
        num = num + 1
    else:
        x = num - 1
        for z in range(2,x):
            if num % z == 0 :
                num = num + 1
            else:
                primes.append(num)
                num = num + 1

print primes[1000]
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `num % 2 == 0` rather than `num / 2 == 0`?

Comment: use %(modulo) operator (Clear your logic first then code)

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few problems (`num / 2 == 0` should be `num % 2 == 0`)<sup>1</sup>, but really, using `continue` and `break` would really help.  e.g.

```
for z in range(2,x):  # xrange would be a performance win on python2.x
    if num % z == 0 :
        num = num + 1
    else:
        primes.append(num)
        num = num + 1
```

In this loop, you could find yourself incrementing `num` a whole bunch of times.  in reality, you only want to increment it once (to move on to the next number).  So here you'd want to `break` after you increment it.  Also, the `else` statement would need to be on the `for` loop:

```
for z in range(2, x):
    if num % z == 0:
        break  # exit the for loop, don't execute `else` clause.
else:
    # only executes if `break` was never encountered.
    primes.append(num)

# This happens no matter what and should only happen once
# Might as well pull it out of the loop.
num += 1
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>the checking for divisibility by 2 is sort of useless here -- It's the first iteration of your loop.  If you used `xrange` (for python2.x) and `break` as I've described, then this optimization (likely) isn't worth it.</sup>

<sup>Aside:  You don't really need to run the loop from `2` to `N - 1`, you can actually get away with running the loop from `2` to `int(math.sqrt(N))` which makes this lots more efficient :-) although still not the best you can do... The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is another algorithm for doing this more efficiently and there's probably even better methods than that (though I'm not an expert in this area)</sup>